# Continuity in Complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am just a little confused in visualising continuity in complex analysis, in my text book continuity for complex functions is defined as:

If $f$ is a complex function defined in some neighbourhood of $a$ (including the point) and is given $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)-f(a)|<\epsilon$  whenever $|z-a|<\delta$

I understand the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, but would my interpretation be correct if I thought of point $a$ forming a ball with radius such that the complex function lies completely within the ball of $a$. So I am imagining that the complex function to be some form of blob that is inside the ball of $a$

If anyone could help me visualise a complex function being defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a circle around the point *a* that can be made as small as you wish. If that condition is satisfied, the function is defined on the point. If such a circle exists for every point of the function on a given set, the function is defined(analytic) on the entire set(subset).